# Reading XML returned from Wikipedia API using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, api, mediawiki

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=pie&prop=revisions&rvprop=content",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xmlData){
        var totalNodes = $('*',xmlData).length; // count XML nodes
        alert("This XML file has " + totalNodes);
    },
    error: function(){
         alert("Could not retrieve XML file.");
    }
 });
```

Not sure what my problem is; can anyone help? The URL I provided is the returned XML for the 'pie' wiki page. You should be able to enter it into your browser and view it. However when I run this code I get the alert from the error function, not success. Any ideas are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You did violate the [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the cross-domain origin policy and you can not resolve it with getting `xml` file. I recommend switching to `JSON`, since `dataType: 'jsonp'` is used for cross-domain requests. Your code will change to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=pie&prop=revisions&rvprop=content",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(jsonData){
        //var totalNodes = $('*',xmlData).length; // count XML nodes
        //alert("This XML file has " + totalNodes);
        console.log(jsonData);
    },
    error: function(){
         alert("Could not retrieve data.");
    }
 });
```

That way you won't need to parse `xml` since you are already getting a Javascript `Object`.